# Is the following statement about PreRender true?

Tags: asp.net

Would a call to a database be called if you put the databind method in the PreRender event of a listbox and the listbox was rendered on the screen for example?  This is a specific example regarding a listbox, but basically does code in PreRender only get called if the control is rendered on the screen.  If this is so, is it good practice to put code into PreRender such as databinding?

Comment: I think there's a good question in here somewhere, but it's confusing me.  Can someone make an attempt to tidy this up?

Comment: I tried to make it sound better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit*: you just changed your question, I think the answer is still yes... but the following still applies:

The `PreRender` event of the `listbox` will only fire if the control is set to `Visible=true` on the page.

So if you do your `DataBind` (and associated database calls) in the `PreRender` it will not call your database if it is set to `Visible=False`.

You can test this quite easily by sticking a break point in the `PreRender` and changing the visibility of the control in the HTML.

Comment: ok, so it has nothing to do with the actual control being drawn on the page. The control has to have a visible property set to false.  If it is true, but not shown on the page, it will still call PreRender.  Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct, the `prerender` event is called for every control on the page, even if they are not in view without scrolling the page. The `prerender` event. take a look through the .NET page life cycle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx and you can see at which point this event is raised.

 If you want to dynamically load data into a control when it is scrolled into view you would need to use some javascript and AJAX.